# How I can repeat a Picture Box on the screen to simulate animation?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I'm programing in C# on Visual Studio 2016, and I'm making a game. I need to repeat a pictureBox. It should begin on the right side of the screen, and move to the left side of the screen.

How can I do this? I currently have this code:

```
while (pictureBox4.Location.X == -10 && pictureBox4.Location.Y == -2)
{
     pictureBox4.Location = new Point(pictureBox4.Location.X - x,  pictureBox4.Location.Y - y);
}
```

x & y are random variables.

Comment: I was surprised when see that you are programming in VIsual Studio 2016) Did you mean 2015 or 2017?

Comment: It's VS 2017, sorry

Comment: `while (pictureBox4.Location.X == -10` shouldn't that be `>=` ?? Also `if` instead of `while`. And be generous and add and `else` clause! Of course without telling us where the code is from all is guesswork..!

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understood your question (which if I didn't please tell me) you should try this:

```
public static class PictureBoxExtension
{
    public static void SetImage(this PictureBox pic, Image image, int repeatX)
    {
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(image.Width * repeatX, image.Height);
        Graphics gp = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        for (int x = 0; x <= bm.Width - image.Width; x += image.Width)
        {
            gp.DrawImage(image, new Point(x, 0));
        }
        pic.Image = bm;
    }
}
```

Comment: You leak `Bitmap` and `Graphics` objects here. The creation of the `Graphics` object should be wrapped in a `using` statement to prevent that, and the old `pic.Image` should be explicitly disposed of.

Comment: Sorry dude It don't function in my program. I need to do that the picturebox started again in the right side of the screen when it arrive in the left side of the screen. Sorry for my english again

Comment: Check this out and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606819/creating-numerous-pictureboxes-by-code-only-one-is-visible